# Highlight usages in file - Resharper color settings

Tags: resharper

When I use 'Highlight usages in file' in Resharper nothing is highlighted in my text editor.
I see the result bar on bottom telling 'Found x usages of ...'. So Resharper finds it but somehow I've lost coloring.

Do you know where I can set it?
I thought about Resharper_Highlght in VS's Fonts and Colors settings but it must be for something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read Usage and Write Usage settings should determine the color in this case.

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors`, find out `ReSharper Read Usage` and `ReSharper Write Usage` in the 'Display items' list and try to set the background color.

Although 'Item foreground' seems not working for me, 'Item background' works fine so I hope it helps you too!

Comment: It turned out that my installation of Resharper was broken. After I repaired it (Control Panel->Add remove programs) it works as you described. Found it before you answered but didn't have time to update my question.